# GDB set variable from the return of whatis

Tags: c++, debugging, stl, gdb

GDB whatis returns the type of variable.
I wonder how I use this result as variable.

```
(gdb) whatis myIntValue
int 
(gdb) set $typeInt = whatis myIntValue // it's impossible but what I want
(gdb) p *($typeInt)0xabcd // this address having an int value
```

I want to use above casting from generic memory address to template class type (which has a very very long name).

And the casting type is very variant it is hard to put every single name while debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to assign a type to a convenience variable.  However, you can do this by saving the value in a convenience variable and then using `typeof`:

```
(gdb) set $x = 23ll
(gdb) ptype $x
type = long long
(gdb) ptype (typeof($x))'z'
type = long long
```

Comment: Thank you! :D happy to see this answer! no more ctrl c + v!!